# Nuxt.generate() inside vuex

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Nuxt allows to generate static routes also if this routes requires a parameters.

How to do if an user register, for example , and I want to generate that specific page `https://website.com/user/newly-created-user-slug`.

According to doc, [nuxt.generate()](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/) is a function that could do that programmatically.

But, from where and how can I call it programmatically within the site?

Comment: You need a separate script that will work on your server that will do it for you

Comment: on your server, you mean to execute through express.js or php laravel? or nuxt server?

Comment: I mean you need external script that will be run from your server. E.g. bash script or js script. It shouldnt be tied to any user interaction

Comment: ah ok. Thank you. If it's the only way, I'll end up using spa. there's no way this is stable on production. I cannot run nuxt generate every time a user is registered or a post is posted.

Comment: yes, thats why for such usecases you usually just run node server with nuxt that will  render page to user each time its requested